# How to <li> align in right in HTML

Tags: html, ios

I am working on a iOS App in which i have to set text from right to left like arabic Language.

I am trying to align the black dot symbol form right on a `UIWebView` in iOS.

My current output is:

[image]

But my requirement is from right side first black dot then text will be align, like arabic style. I am right in code also text-align:right, but its coming first text from right then Black dot. My code is :

[image]

Comment: I got a solution. I have to set a black dot image in right side like: <IMG SRC="dot.png" Align=right>, but its not correct way. I want to trough coding i have to do using <li>

Comment: Use direction:rtl; in your code at ul level

Comment: can u share some code for this ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">
        ul 
        {
            text-align: right;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change text direction in CSS.

```
ul {
    direction: rtl; /*RIGHT TO LEFT DIRECTION*/
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ehj1cjzd/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure may be this code can help you.

CSS CODE

```
ul
{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: right;
}

li
{
padding-right: .6em;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tea</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css:

```
ul{   
direction:rtl;
list-style-type: bullet;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0uvucu3c/)

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
ul {
    direction: rtl;
}
```